# How can I verify every query log from express.js server to mongo db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

### How can I verify every query from express.js server to mongo db?

I looked [manage-the-database-profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/)
I had set profile level as `db.setProfilingLevel(2,200)`. At my page is calling following mongo DB using mongoose like following

```
mycollection.findOne({MyId: 1}, function(err, data){

    })
```

When I look log file, there's no access to "mycollection". 
Also, the log file sometime do contains query on some of my page like following.

2014-07-30T13:11:59.258-0700 [conn33] query myDB.myOtherCollection query: { MyID: 100 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoskip:0 nscanned:850 nscannedObjects:850 keyUpdates:0 numYields:7 locks(micros) r:6101 nreturned:0 reslen:20 3ms

---

So what is a way to show all query log to mongo database?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using mongoose, you can see the queries executed by enabling debug.

```
mongoose.set('debug', true)
```

Comment: This's great! I didn't know this. I'm able to resolve part of my problem, which I know how many query is go to access to mongodb via mongoose. However, I hope they could add how long query was.

Answer (score 1):

[`db.setProfilingLevel`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) has an optional `level` argument that, when set to 2, records all operations in the `system.profile` collection of the database, *not* in the log file. The `slowMS` argument determines how slow a query must be before it is logged to the log file.

If you want to closely monitor activity in your collections, consider using [MMS](https://mms.mongodb.com/) for monitoring as it exposes a lot of useful usage, performance, and profiling information in a more friendly format than `system.profile`.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to set the second argument, slowMS, to 1ms, this will log all queries that take more than 1ms -- which is pretty much all of them.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. 1ms could log lots of stuff. However, I think if the query is less than 1ms, then query log won't show.